# Is AWS S3 read guaranteed to return a newly created object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been reading the docs regarding read-after-write consistency with AWS S3 but I'm still unsure about this.

If I write an object to S3 and after getting a successful response from my write operation, I *immediately* attempt to read it, is the read operation guaranteed to return the object?

In other words, is it possible that the read operation will fail because it can't find the object? Because the read happened too soon after the write?

I'm only talking about new PUTs here, not updates to existing objects.

Comment: Update: as of Dec 2020, S3 offers strong consistency for all GET, PUT and LIST operations: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-update-strong-read-after-write-consistency/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes guaranteed to return the object (only for new objects) with one caveat:

As per [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel):

> Amazon S3 provides read-after-write consistency for PUTS of new
>   objects in your S3 bucket in all regions with one caveat. The caveat
>   is that if you make a HEAD or GET request to the key name (to find if
>   the object exists) before creating the object, Amazon S3 provides
>   eventual consistency for read-after-write.
>
> Amazon S3 offers eventual consistency for overwrite PUTS and DELETES
>   in all regions.

EDIT: credits to @Michael - sqlbot, more on HEAD (or) GET caveat:

> If you send a GET or HEAD before the object exists, such as to check whether there's an object there before you upload, then the upload is not immediately consistent for read requests even after the upload is complete, because S3 has already made the only immediately consistent internal query it's going to make for that object, discovering, authoritatively, that there's no such key. The object creation becomes eventually consistent, since the creation has to "overwrite" the previous lookup that found nothing.

Based on following table provided in the link, "consistent reads" will never be stale.
[image]

Above provided link has nice example regarding how "read-after-write consistency" & "eventual consistency" works.

I would like to add this caution note to this answer to make things more clear:

> Amazon S3 achieves high availability by replicating data across multiple servers within Amazon's data centers. If a PUT request is successful, your data is safely stored. However, information about the changes must replicate across Amazon S3, which can take some time, and so you might observe the following behaviors:
>
> A process writes a new object to Amazon S3 and immediately lists keys
>   within its bucket. Until the change is fully propagated, the object
>   might not appear in the list.

Comment: That's great, but I don't really understand that caveat. It says if you make a HEAD or GET `before` creating the object... but if you were doing that, then it's not a read-after-write operation, so why is it relevant? That's like a read-before-write, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: But a GET is a read, isn't it? And they're supposed to be safe after the first write. But then the caveat contradicts that?

Comment: You are misinterpreting the caveat. If you send a `GET` or `HEAD` *before* the object exists, such as to check whether there's an object there before you upload, then the upload is **not** immediately consistent for read requests *even after* the upload is complete, because S3 has already made the only immediately consistent internal query it's going to make for that object, discovering, authoritatively, that there's no such key.  The object creation becomes eventually consistent, since the creation has to "overwrite" the previous lookup that found nothing.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks! I deleted my comments. Yours is very valid and thanks for the comment. Learning alot from your comments. But one thing I am not sure is, what practical reason someone would initiate upload without inspecting GET call results? any thoughts.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you ask *"what practical reason someone would initiate upload without inspecting `GET` call results?"* I wrote a utility for uploading tarball backups.  Before it allows you to upload, it checks whether the object exists, which means either you typed the wrong object key are going to accidentally overwrite the file, or you've already uploaded the file, so if `GET` succeeds, my uploader throws an error unless you specify `--overwrite`.  But normally there's not a need to check whether an object already exists before uploading it.

Comment: In this example, you are waiting for GET success/failure before proceeding with upload right? entire this thing happens "before you initiate upload (for new objects)". Based on first comment, if understand correctly, GET request should initiate first & stay longer than "upload" request. What example scenarios these types of calls might happen? this confusion is what prompted me to misinterpret and think that any GET call during object upload will become eventual consistent (in cases like multi-threaded), NOT read-after-write. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot could you elaborate more on your first comment explaining the caveat ? ( in possibly simpler language ) ? the way you seem to describe the scenario is that s3 should have been in an existing consistent state for that object before the PUT( and doing a GET breaks this ).

Comment: @AbhinavVishak If you send a `GET` or `HEAD` before the object exists, such as to check whether there's an object there before you upload, then the next `GET` or `HEAD` request made immediately *after* the upload is no longer guaranteed to return the new object: it *may* return `NoSuchKey` for a short time.  Objects may take a short time to appear, **if** you check for them before creating them for the first time.  If you do not check for an object's existence before uploading it, and then you upload it, then you'll find that very next request is guaranteed to return the new object.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot is this a direct consequence of s3 Implementation ? for eg. in the caveat case, the authorative GET happened  within the last 10 ms  so the implementation decides that it is authoritative and doesnt do an update when the PUT occurs ( or something like that ) ?

Comment: "Amazon S3 offers eventual consistency for overwrite PUTS and DELETES in all Regions." is not on [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel) link you provided anymore.  Is that statement still true?  Is there any mention about eventual consistency for objects on AWS Documentation anywhere now?  We're potentially running into this issue but [it seems read-after-write consistency is available](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/12/amazon-s3-now-delivers-strong-read-after-write-consistency-automatically-for-all-applications/)