# Uploading file to S3 and immediately executing processing code when the file is available

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to know if I am overcomplicating my application. I am using the AWS PHP SDK to upload a file to S3, then using S3 Events to trigger an SNS topic to process my file.

My reason for using S3 Events is that I am afraid of executing the processing code immediately after executing the uploading code; I want verification that the object was successfully uploaded to S3. I am afraid of the processing code executing before the upload to S3 has completed. The reason I am posting here is that I realize I am not using JS and that PHP is not natively asynchronous.

Does anyone have experience with this? If so, am I safe to forego SNS and just "assume" (horrible) that the object will be in S3 by the time by processing code runs, or should I continue down this path of using S3 Events/SNS to alert my application when the file is available in S3?

Thank you all in advance

Example code:

```
$s3Client->upload("somefile.jpg");

// have no idea if this file is available yet, but...
$dataModel->process("https://s3-us-west-mock-us-url.amazonaws.com/somefile.jpg");
```

Comment: I would probably [poll](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html#uploading-a-file) S3 till the object is accessible

Answer (score 2):

Can you just assume that the upload was successful? Of course you can't, this is an operation that involves network communication therefore latency is always present.

Once the upload to the S3 bucket is successful, you will get 200 OK response, which means that you don't have to use SNS or anything like that if you just want to wait for the upload to finish (just wait for the response).

Better approach (if possible) would be to actually use S3 events and subscribe a lambda function to that event and let it handle the processing. That way you don't have to care about that at all in your application and just assume that something else (lambda) takes care of it.

Comment: This is correct, with two caveats: if you are overwriting an existing object, you may get the old object if you request the object immediately after the upload is complete.  If you do a `GET` or `HEAD` to check for the object's existence, before uploading, then the same thing may happen -- download after upload may return the new object or may replay the "not found" for a short time.  The object is guaranteed not to be lost ("is durably stored") when successful upload finishes, but you *might* not fetch it on the first try, in those two cases.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44679306/1695906